# Why valid json return error in simplejson loads?

Tags: python

I have a simple example:

```
test = '{ "text": "\"test\""}'
```

It is a valid json ( see http://jsonlint.com/ ).

But `simplejson.loads(test)` return error :

```
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 12 (char 12)
```

Why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, `\"` means `"` only. So, the string is actually processed as

```
{ "text": ""test""}
```

As you see now, there is an empty string before `test` and `test` is not enclosed by double quotes. So, you just have to escape the `\` as well, like this

```
test = '{ "text": "\\"test\\"" }'
```

Or create the text as a raw string, like this

```
test = r'{ "text": "\"test\"" }'
```

Comment: But how to parse valid json in Python ? Use hack for preparejson ?

Comment: @Bdfy Simply use `json` module. `import json; print(json.loads(test))`